# App.config not located by a .net assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, .net-assembly

I have an ASP.NET application which is adding up .NET assembly in its reference. The assembly is a private assembly and it has a config file with some keys under `<AppSettings>`.

Now the problem is when I am debugging my ASP.NET application the assembly is not loading the app.config file.

I observed that under the property of referenced assembly I have `Copy Local=true`.

Can anyone please help or point out if i am missing some basics?

Comment: You need to collect all pertinent settings in the web.config file of the main asp.net application. Only the config file of the running application (be it web or desktop) is loaded automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect all pertinent settings into the web.config file of the main ASP.NET application. Only the config file of the running application (be it web or desktop) is loaded automatically.

Look up some articles on how config files work in the .NET environment to learn the basics of what is and isn't loaded, it'll definitely help you avoid headaches like this in the future.

Alternatively, if you know the name of your assembly's config file you can add a `file` attribute to your `<AppSettings>` element, pointing to that file if it's copied to the same directory as the web.config is in.

```
<appSettings file="privateassembly.config">
```

Please note that any appsetting with the same name declared in the web.config will be overridden by the privateassembly.config. Also note that any change to privateassembly.config (while the ASP.NET application is running) will not reset the application pool and thus will not be loaded into the AppDomain.